# How to create conditions based on user role using JSF/MyFaces?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, myfaces, tomahawk

What options do I have to read the roles of the current user from my JSP pages? I'm aware of the `visibleOnUserRole="myRole"` attribute on Tomahawk components, but I need roles for a bit more complicated things than simple visibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ExternalContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) exposes user and role information.

```
public class RolesAccess implements Serializable {

    public String getUserPrincipalName() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Principal principal = context.getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
        if(principal == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return principal.getName();
    }

    public String getUser() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return context.getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
    }

    public boolean isManager() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return context.getExternalContext().isUserInRole("manager");
    }

}
```

If you're using JSF in servlets, this information maps to the values exposed by the [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

You can use managed beans to expose values to the view via the [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html).

```
<f:view>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{rolesBean.userPrincipalName}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="#{rolesBean.user}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="#{rolesBean.manager}" />
</f:view>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java EE 6 (which wasn't available when this question was asked/answered), you can test roles directly from the `request` variable in your Facelets code. This is super-convenient.

E.g.

```
<h:outputText value="hi, admin!" rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('Admin')}" />
```